# Detect adjustment inside modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a modal plugin. Currently the modal will center itself in the middle of a page and will adjust if the display dimensions change.

I would like to do the same adjustment if some action within the model takes place, for example, a link clicked and a hidden content shows.

Here's what I have now:

```
// load modal
boxPos(el);

// adjust position and dimentions of the modal
$(window).resize(function() {
    boxPos(el);
});
```

Shall I just listen to "click" event or is there a way to detect show()/hide()? But then again, there could be slideDown etc. How would I implement it?

UPDATE----------------------

Ok, partial success... I've added a function at the bottom to react to click on a link, div span or input element. I calls the re-size function but before the window is re-sized. Perhaps I can delay that re-size and the and some sliding action on re-size? Or not...

Here's the entire modal code:

```
;(function ($, window, document) {

// window and document are passed through as local variable rather than global
// as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
// minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

function boxPos(el) {

    // calculate/set height of content area         
    var winH = $(window).height(),                          // viewport height
        winW = $(window).width(),                           // viewport width
        ttlH = $('#bmcTitle').outerHeight(true),            // modal title element height
        auxH = $('#bmcAux').outerHeight(true),              // auxiliary area element height
        ftrH = $('#bmcFooter').outerHeight(true),           // modal footer element height
        cntH = winH - ttlH - auxH - ftrH - 150;             // calculated content area height 

    $('#bmcContent').css('max-height', cntH+'px');

    // position modal in center
    var boxH = $('#bmc').outerHeight(true),                 // real modal height
        bmcH = ttlH + auxH + cntH + ftrH + 80,              // modal height plus content padding/margin  
        bmcW = $('#bmc').outerWidth(true),                  // real modal width 
        bmcT = (winH - (boxH < bmcH ? boxH : bmcH)) / 2,    // top offset for centering         
        bmcL = (winW - bmcW) / 2;                           // left offset for centering 

    $('#bmc').css({ 'top': bmcT+'px', 'left': bmcL+'px' });
}

$.fn.bmc = function() { 

    // REQUIRED -- modal title
    var el = $(this),
        boxHeader = el.attr('title'),                       // modal title          
        boxContnt = el.find('#bmcMid').show().html(),       // content area will overflow if content exceeds max space          
        overlay   = $('<div />').css('opacity','.8').addClass('bmcOverlay');

    // check if form is present
    if (el.find('form').length > 0) {
        var boxForm      = el.find('form').clone().empty(),
            boxFormTags  = boxForm[0].outerHTML,
            boxFormOpen  = boxFormTags.split("</")[0];  
            boxFormClose = '</form>';
    } else {
        var boxFormOpen  = '',
            boxFormClose = '';
    }

    // OPTIONAL -- reserved spot for anything static on top of modal box, like errors, or description.
    if (el.find('#bmcTop').length > 0) {
        var boxAuxilr = (el.find('#bmcTop').html() == '' ? '' : '<div id="bmcAux">'+el.find('#bmcTop').html()+'</div>');            
    } else {
        var boxAuxilr = '';
    }

    // OPTIONAL -- static area at the bottom of modal. Put buttons here.
    if (el.find('#bmcBtm').length > 0) {
        var boxFooter = (el.find('#bmcBtm').html() == '' ? '' : '<div id="bmcFooter">'+el.find('#bmcBtm').html()+'</div>');
    } else {
        var boxFooter = '';     
    }

    // assemble modal box
    var modalBx = $('<div id="bmc"><div id="bmcClose"></div><div id="bmcTitle">'+ boxHeader +'</div>'+ boxAuxilr + boxFormOpen +'<div id="bmcContent">'+ boxContnt +'</div>'+ boxFooter + boxFormClose +'</div>');  

    $('body').append(overlay, modalBx).hide().fadeIn(500);

    // load modal
    boxPos(el);

    // adjust position and dimentions of the modal
    $(window).resize(function() {
        boxPos(el);
    });

    $('a, div, span, input').children().on('click', function() {
        boxPos(el);
    });

    // close and remove modal
    $('#bmcClose, .bmcClose').on('click', function() {
        modalBx.remove();
        overlay.remove();
    });

    return;
};
```

})(jQuery, window, document);

Comment: You would need to hook all the events that are happening in the modal.  Maybe create a custom event using `.bind('modalChange', function() { ... })` and call it from any other event as needed with `.trigger('modalChange')`.

Comment: You mean using this function from withing the plug-in or outside, where I can actions that affect elements within the modal?

Comment: Bind inside, and trigger outside for events outside of your plugins' control/knowledge.

Comment: OK thanks... not really sure how to go do that though. I guess I'm more clear on the second part. Whenever I call some action I can add $(this).trigger('modalChange'); how do I "hook all the events"?.. Sorry, it's probably quite obvious, but I've never done that.

Comment: Tried adding this inside plug-in: $(this)children().bind('click', function() {
   boxPos(el);
  }); Was hoping that if an element is clicked it'll call the function for reposition... fail.

Comment: Still wonder if there is a way to keep it all withing the plug-in similar how it detects and acts on window resize...

Comment: Well, if you know what events will happen in the window, then you could rely on the bubbling of events, ie. catch them after the content has dealt with them.

Comment: I'm thinking any "click" of a link or "change" of the select option cover most of them. Possibly even .mouseup(). This is just going to be a check, i.e. the function will get new window dimensions and make adjustments.

Comment: You can use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method on the container of the modal with an element type or class type to monitor.

Comment: Is there a way to make it generic, regardless of an element?  After all with jQuery you can make any element clickable... Maybe something like $(this).on('mouseup', function(event) { boxPos(el); }); I think I'm coding myself into the dark woods that I'll never be able to find my way out... :)

Comment: If the `$(this)` is the container for the modal and all `mouseup` events within it are allowed to bubble up, then yes.